# Deny access to file in htaccess, on certain conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file

I can successfully block access to a file in htaccess with this:

```
<Files "image1.jpg">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

It works for one file, but I want to block access to thousands of files based on a pattern.

So something like this:

```
<Files "source_*">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Note the * wildcard. If a file name starts with "source_" then it should deny access.

What would that look like in the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive you're looking for is [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch). With it, you can use Regex to specify files. Probably something like:

```
<FilesMatch "source_.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
# ...
</FilesMatch>
```

If you want to test your Regular Expression more easily, I'd recommend [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Many thanks Dan S. That's what I needed. Now I just need to learn regex. :|